# How to get values from multiple bucket on firebase database with kodular

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to to built a search in kodular get values from firebase realtime, for um bucket is working fine, but I want to get values from another TAGS in the same database.

When I do a search in this way it's work fine:

[image]

[image]

But I want to do a search in others TAGS for exemplo KCE/Produtos/Limpeza, KCE/Produtos/Caro, KCE/Produtos/Casa.

Firebase

[image]
I'll show what I gonna doing.

I'm trying something like this, but I retrieve the values in different format.

[image]

I want to get values from multiple TAGS in Firebase Database in the same format as when I get values from complete bucket KCE/Produtos/Limpeza.

What should I do? Can I do something like this:
[image]